# ¿Como validar que un Texboxt no tenga una ","(coma)?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Les coloco en contexto, tengo un `Textbox` llamado **CAMPOPNeta**, el cual solo acepta números  y `"."`(punto), esta programado con el código siguiente el cual es llamado con el método `KeyPress` del `Textbox`:

```
private void SoloNumPunto(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Hasta allí todo correcto, El problema es que necesito validar que el `Texbox` no tenga `","`comas...Pero si el usuario Copia y Pega algo como **1,234.56** necesito validar que no lleve esa coma y que coloque o se coloque **1234.56**. Hasta donde se, se debería agregar en el método `Validating` como lo tengo en otro `Texbox` llamado **CampoAño**:

```
private void CAMPOaño_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(CAMPOaño.Text=="")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            int año = Convert.ToInt32(CAMPOaño.Text);
            if (año < 1997 || año > 2025)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Rango Minimo 1997, Rango Maximo 2025", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                CAMPOaño.Text = "";
                CAMPOaño.Focus();
            }
            Convert.ToString(CAMPOaño.Text);
        }
    }
```

Quise probar algo como esto, pero creo que ni siquiera es codigo C#:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^\d+(,\d+)*$"))
{

}
```

Al final lo que busco es esto:

Si CAMPOPNeta Tiene "," coma, entonces: Mensaje al usuario: El campo no puede llevar coma. o en otro caso que elimine la coma...

Espero puedan ayudarme, de ante mano Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola es algo muy fácil según lo que entendí, simplemente la cadena de string usa Srtring.Contains y este te devuelve un bool.

```
string s1 = "Texto equis , asdkj aslñkdj añskld";
string s2 = ",";
bool b = s1.Contains(s2);

// b = true;
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/contains

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió... y es cierto, es muy simple. Habia pensado ya varias lineas de código pero esto es excelente y fácil.

Comment: Hola, puse referencia mal, es esta =D

https://www.dotnetperls.com/contains